# Synchronize files between 2 folders on computer and external drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, sync

I bought an external drive and want to use it partially for store, partially as back up. What I would like to see is that some folder (named.. let's say "Sync") is always the same on my Mac and on the drive. I can change "Sync" content on my mac without the drive, mount the drive and "Sync" on the drive should be updated automatically. I can change "Sync" on the drive using other computer, mount it on my mac and "Sync" on my mac must be updated automatically.

Usual software propose syncronization between two computers. Or one way backup on one computer using unremovable disk.
How to achieve the effect I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sync Folders](http://www.greenworldsoft.com/sync-folders-pro-help.php#Sync-modes) does the job. Started version is free on AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Compare & Sync Folders. It is very similar to Sync Folders, which I used for a couple of years. I changed to C&S because before the actual sync, you can very clearly see what and how is going to be changed in each syncing folder. Also, the UI of C&S is quite nice. You can have a free version with a limited number sync modes, and then buy only specific features. I used it for a couple of days and just bought all the features. I truly works well. If automating the syncs would be important, then I'd recommend Sync Folders.
Note: I know some explanations by the developer can be somewhat confusing, but I sent a bunch of questions and s/he responded promptly.